# Fragment fecha ao clicar em TextView Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

Salve lista!
Seguinte, tenho uma activity onde chamo um fragment usando

```
// ...
val manager = supportFragmentManager
val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()

_Fragment = AcvtFragmentView()
val args = Bundle()
args.putBoolean("cal_warning", true)
args.putString("ID", ID)
args.putString("name", kName)
args.putString("email", kEmail)
args.putString("date", date)
args.putString("time", time)
args.putString("keypub", keypub)
args.putString("msg", interpretation)
_Fragment!!.setArguments(args)

transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentview, _Fragment!!)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
// ...
```

Tá funcionando bem, mas o que ocorre é que quando ele abre na tela dessa activity e eu clico em um TextView qualquer dentro desse fragmento ele fecha sozinho e eu preciso digitar texto nesses campos.
Já revirei a internet e estou a dias nessa pendenga.

Será que alguém aqui poderia me ajudar com isso?

Agradece

Segue o código da activity AcvtFragmenteView:

```
class AcvtFragmentView : Fragment() {
// ...
internal var actionCallBack: onActionEventListener? = null

interface onActionEventListener {
    fun dlgActions(id: Int,name: String?,email: String?,datepub: String?,interpretation: String?)
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    mContext = context
    try {
        actionCallBack = context as onActionEventListener
    } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
        throw ClassCastException("$activity must implement onSomeEventListener")
    }
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    mydb = DreamsItemHelper(mContext)
}
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_interprete, container, false)

    val ID = arguments!!.getString("ID")
    val dDate = arguments!!.getString("date")
    val tTime = arguments!!.getString("time")
    val keypub = arguments!!.getString("keypub")
    val interp = arguments!!.getString("msg")

    date = window!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.datepubItView) as TextView
    date!!.text = dDate

    val kName = arguments!!.getString("name")
    val kEmail = arguments!!.getString("email")

    val name = window!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.interName) as EditText
    name.setText(kName)
    val email = window!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.interEmail) as EditText
    email.setText(kEmail)
    interpretation = window!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.edtInterpretation) as EditText
    interpretation!!.text = interp

    btnsend = window!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.btnSendToInterpret) as TextView
    if (interp != null) {
        btnsend!!.isEnabled = false
    }

    btnsend!!.setOnClickListener {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()

        val iName = name.text.toString()
        val iEmail = email.text.toString()
        val aDay = fillLeft(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString(), "0")
        val aMonth = fillLeft((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).toString(), "0")
        val aYear = fillLeft(c.get(Calendar.YEAR).toString(), "0")

        val lang = Locale.getDefault().language
        var dateGlobal = ""
        when (lang.toLowerCase()) {
            "en" -> dateGlobal = aYear + "-" + aMonth + "-" + aDay
            "es" -> dateGlobal = aDay + "-" + aMonth + "-" + aYear
            "pt" -> dateGlobal = aDay + "-" + aMonth + "-" + aYear
        }
        val inter = (interpretation as EditText).text.toString()
        val id = Integer.valueOf(ID!!)
        val isOk = !iName.equals("") && !iEmail.equals("") && iEmail.contains("@") && iEmail.contains(".")
        if (isOk)
            SendToInterpret().execute(ID,iName,iEmail,qDate,tTime,keypub,dateGlobal,inter
            )
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext,getString(R.string.toastNameAndEmailEmpty),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    val btnclose = window!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.btnCloseInterpret) as TextView
    btnclose.setOnClickListener { setGone() }

    window!!.requestLayout()
    return window
}
```

Comment: Já que está usando Kotlin, dê uma olha no plugin de View binding do Android Extensions, com ele você não precisa mais de `findViewById`, basta chamar a view pelo seu Id no layout (no momento apropriado, nesse caso, no `onViewCreated`) https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o problema é na variável (possivelmente global) `window`. Você está atribuindo a ela o layout raiz e logo em seguida utilizando os `findViewById()` com ela. Ainda mais, está fazendo tudo isso ainda no `onCreateView`, deve-se manipular views apenas no `onViewCreated`, chamado logo após o onCreateView ter retornada a sua view, e só então usá-la em um estado "seguro".

A minha sugestão é, usar a view raiz retornada pelo onCreateView no onViewCreated para instanciar as suas outras views.

```
class AcvtFragmentView : Fragment() {
    // ...
    internal var actionCallBack: onActionEventListener? = null

    interface onActionEventListener {
        fun dlgActions(id: Int, name: String?, email: String?, datepub: String?, interpretation: String?)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        mContext = context
        try {
            actionCallBack = context as onActionEventListener
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException("$activity must implement onSomeEventListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        mydb = DreamsItemHelper(mContext)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_interprete, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val ID = arguments!!.getString("ID")
        val dDate = arguments!!.getString("date")
        val tTime = arguments!!.getString("time")
        val keypub = arguments!!.getString("keypub")
        val interp = arguments!!.getString("msg")

        // date = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.datepubItView) as TextView
        date = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.datepubItView)
        date.text = dDate

        val kName = arguments!!.getString("name")
        val kEmail = arguments!!.getString("email")

        //val name = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.interName) as EditText
        val name = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.interName)
        name.setText(kName)

        // val email = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.interEmail) as EditText
        val email = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.interEmail)
        email.setText(kEmail)

        // interpretation = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.edtInterpretation) as EditText
        interpretation = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edtInterpretation)
        interpretation.text = interp

        //btnsend = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.btnSendToInterpret) as TextView
        btnsend = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.btnSendToInterpret)
        if (interp != null) {
            btnsend.isEnabled = false
        }

        btnsend.setOnClickListener {
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()

            val iName = name.text.toString()
            val iEmail = email.text.toString()
            val aDay = fillLeft(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString(), "0")
            val aMonth = fillLeft((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).toString(), "0")
            val aYear = fillLeft(c.get(Calendar.YEAR).toString(), "0")

            val lang = Locale.getDefault().language
            val dateGlobal = when (lang.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())) {
                "en" -> "$aYear-$aMonth-$aDay"
                "es" -> "$aDay-$aMonth-$aYear"
                "pt" -> "$aDay-$aMonth-$aYear"
                else ->  ""
            }

            val inter = (interpretation as EditText).text.toString()
            val id = Integer.valueOf(ID)
            val isOk = iName != "" && iEmail != "" && iEmail.contains("@") && iEmail.contains(".")
            if (isOk)
                SendToInterpret().execute(ID, iName, iEmail, qDate, tTime, keypub, dateGlobal, inter)
            else
                Toast.makeText(mContext, getString(R.string.toastNameAndEmailEmpty), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        //val btnclose = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.btnCloseInterpret) as TextView
        val btnclose = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.btnCloseInterpret)
        btnclose.setOnClickListener { setGone() }

        //view.requestLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa Lennoard, eu positivei a resposta porque ela esta correta, mas eu resolvi de outra forma, que foi extendendo a minha classe de um **DialogFragment** ao inves da de um **Fragment**, Valeus, "quando vc casar, a mulher eh sua", rererere